# Parsing text written the millitext font

Tags: code-golf

## Reading the text of the millitext font

There is a font [here](http://www.msarnoff.org/millitext/) that fits each character into a single, 1x5 pixel block. It does this (assuming you're using an LCD screen) by using the RGB channels of each pixel to expand the one pixel into three subcolumns, one for each channel. Your task is to take in a string of text encoded in this font and 'decode' it.

## Millitext Alphabet

```
CHARACTER: 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
ENCODING:  WYWBMRRMMMWYWYWWWMWBMRMYGYGYCWMMMMMW
           MGBWMRRMMMMMRMRRRMGBMRWMMMMMRGMMMMMB
           MGWWWWWBWWWYRMWWMWGBYRWMMYMYGGMMWGGG
           MGRBBBMBMBMMRMRRMMGBMRMMMRWMBGMCWMGR
           WWWWBWWBWWMYWYWRWMWWMWMMGRCMYGWBMMGW
```

I've abbreviated each color to a one character symbol (R=red, G=green, B=blue, C=cyan, Y=yellow, M=magenta, W=white).

## Input Format

The input format for this is pretty open. You can have the input be an array containing each column, an array containing each row, a `char[][]`, or anything like that. You can also choose to use the full words "red", "green", "blue", with uppercase/lowercase of your choice (but it must be consistent for each word! You cannot use "RED" and also do "green" or "Blue").

If your language happens to support it, you can also have input be colors (however that might work, I don't know off-hand).

You can assume that the input will ONLY contain encoded characters in the alphabet above (in particular, there will be no spaces or punctuation in your output).

## Output Format

You can either output a string or some sort of character array. You can chose whether the letters are uppercase or lowercase, but they must all have the same case.

## Example

```
MWRRGMGYRY
MRRRMMMMRM
WWRRMWMYRM -> HELLOWORLD
MRRRMWMMRM
MWWWGMGMWY
```

## Rules

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

## Test set

```
WMWGMWWMYYGMYWGMBMMYWYGMWYWMWRWWMYGW
GMRMMGRMMMMMMRMMBMWMRMMMRMGMRRMBMMMR
GWWMMGRYYYMWMWMGBMWYWMMMWYGWWRWGGMMM -> THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG
GMRWMGRMMMMWMRMMBMMRRMMCRMGMRRMRGMMM
GMWCWWWMYMGMMRGMWWMRWYGBWMGMWWMWGYGW
```

Comment: I feel like you either hardcode all letters or use a Mathematica builtin here.

Comment: Thanks for that @Arnauld, guess it didn't like it when I copied my test case

Comment: Nice first challenge, BTW!

Comment: Your 8 is wrongly encoded as `MMWMW` instead of `WMWMW`. Same for 9 (top is M instead of W). This has likely caused answers using the wrong encoding as well.

Comment: [Here is the fixed font](https://tio.run/##fVNNT4QwEL3zK@ZWkHVi4scFuOjBkxcv1iAxm/0wmqU1y8aw0f3tOKUU2lI9lAd9b6aPx/Cx/Fo2q/375@FcyPWm67ZSHKCAMgJgnHPgHEEjLeTT/WwhzPRWDeJwjzjsIWCvtdGq8RfnbNGbogdVoBq6TTFcOO6jozM9Ru6vg3EwGOCo3jUVSgYxkNSYgpeSMWU0tinuJueYMrV6eaZwSgsn5w6Gk@LhpPwaPvUypuxPOXgYTP2TDs4S8WbKTsSfSXQO0wacOXNfdthjUZVFW7mPGxp6xhZwJLzICHK4JkjTBL7Jt5IITQmiLm8IDafZmthWK1qlIJgEADX8FBCrv6s8VqWAM7iCFNoKCjqXswTyHNqsF5/6awMpMa@P98@3D3dPrKwrxSpOMy@CZdEpWknRyN0Gd/ItbpKs634B) (several other characters are wrong).

Comment: I don't know if you wanted your test set to include all letters from the English alphabet or not, but if son that's called a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) and "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPEDOVERTHELAZYDOG" isn't one as its missing an "S", if you wanted it to be it should be "THEQUICKBROWNFOXJUMPESOVERTHELAZYDOG"

Comment: Is it possibile to take a matrix of ASCII code points instead of the characters M,W etc (e.g.  M = 77, W = 87 etc) ?

Comment: @MindSwipe small correction: "JUMPES" is not a word, but you could use "DOGS" (sadly, one character longer, 37).  Personally, I like "Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz", at 31 letters.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades JUMPS is a possibility.And you can lose two characters by changing one of the THEs for A.

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>103 100 93 92</s>  90 bytes

*Saved 9 bytes thanks to @ShieruAsakoto*

Takes input as an array of columns. Returns an array of characters.

```javascript
a=>a.map(s=>"H-L-D--VGQ87MR6TZ-KJ9WC05BUXF1YI2EON3S-A-P4"[parseInt(s,35)%1161%219%152%43])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZF9b9NADMb/76c4TaqSiCRq@jKYqlTiwjADPLbjxRxRhK6lhU1bUzUV2oT47J2dS9lEXhTf@cnPj33X7rdrFturzS5Z1z@W@1W@d/nMpbduEzb57OhN8j55lSRf4PLFczTHn74l796eUDGY6M9fX2f2bHj64Xz0MXmZXIyPyo3bNsuz9S5s4tEk6mfZcdYfZif9bDLsj0dVtN8tm53KlVP5TP1Rcw7LaqrKNE1dOaiqdFVvT93iVxh@j9VdJKpyEKssVsNYjWI1flTcS3Je3lXqGfPK@4rD2G/kKgiiaKoW9bqpb5bpTf0zXIXzKL2ur9ahz/3t9cRLWPaUCsiSRmMQkSNLRChrtMB3QSgXBbEoETR5JbLAcASs9BID7UcflCSX5tcaFCRoK0rLXFYSAByURmuNcrdMbJkCJNSAbACMV3ZAflB8cl64rDcFQ9kzFw16VTR90huSYWNgje2qGW/f4IHJa@Yd1m2eHvNcgvh/nsz/ZGlJDFgLbAfEPrsSJWeMJKCbGkg74KcmoeYCbYPM5Wpawk5JbTvWWpTOeBBCk3PhjCEZHP5jUsckz2xHV3RM81RJhZyp5Yzsc2iYxwcJ/lxsN7X9Aw)

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Thanks! The multiplication was not a good idea. I saved 1 more byte with 3 mod's.

Comment: Those are some big modulos over there... maybe you can improve them more so the `-`s disappear! :D

Comment: After a whole night of brute-force I got a 90 with 4 mods: `a=>a.map(s=>"H-L-D--VGQ87MR6TZ-KJ9WC05BUXF1YI2EON3S-A-P4"[parseInt(s,35)%1161%219%152%43])`.

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Unfortunately, the font described in the challenge is wrong. Waiting for a possible update from the OP.

Comment: @Arnauld For the fixed one my progress now is a 93: `a=>a.map(s=>"UIR-L68N--W-X7B-FH-D-EZ--902-S4M5GJCQT3PKV-A1-YO"[parseInt(s,35)%464%107%99%52])`

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 50 bytes

```
Oḅ⁹%211“ẎP\7ßɱðvs*Ḋ⁹UfRMJiẒVƑ).Z½Ƈ"}~ḌyH⁵Ŀ⁶Ṿ‘iⱮịØB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4Y7WR407VY0MDR81zHm4qy8gxvzw/JMbD28oK9Z6uKMLKBeaFuTrlflw16SwYxM19aIO7T3WrlRb93BHT6XHo8atR/Y/atz2cOe@Rw0zMh9tXPdwd/fhGU7///@PVgp3BwIlHSVf33BfXyAdHgSEQNodKOAMFgcyQOJAZWA6KAgs7@sbCVYfCaQjobQvRJ8v1LxwiLwv3NwgFHl3sLgTEIQj2QPSBjUXrB7mHpA5kSj6fZ2dUOQh9uPyTxDU3eEwcSd3qD8g6tHNDw8CuScWAA)

A monadic link accepting the input as a list of columns and outputting a Jelly string of the translation. Full explanation to follow, but relies on the fact that each possible set of 5 letters is unique when converted to code points, converted back from base-256 to decimal and then mod 211.

[Alternative using Arnauld’s fixed font](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9//4Y4eVUMT40cNcw7v84j2etS4z@rIxvCjk@0Pz3M9tPRwm7fbie0VMdpKZnmHFikUHNpgGeVzaPOhvb6xhzc6PGqYkflo47qHu7sPz3D6//9/tFK4OxAo6Sj5@ob7@gLp8CAgBNLuQAFnsDiQARIHKgPTQUFgeV/fSLD6SCAdCaV9Ifp8oeaFQ@R94eYGoci7g8WdgCAcyR6QNqi5YPUw94DMiUTR7@vshCIPsR@Xf4Kg7g6HiTu5Q/0BUY9ufngQyD2xAA) (49 bytes and using same principle.)

#### Explanation

```
O                   | Convert to code points
 ḅ⁹                 | Convert from base 256 to decimal
   %211             | Mod 211
       “Ẏ...Ṿ‘iⱮ    | Find indices in [209,80,92,55,21,162,24,118,115,42,193,137,85,102,82,77,74,105,189,86,146,41,46,90,10,144,34,125,126,173,121,72,133,199,134,186]
                ịØB | Index into 01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Answer (score 7):

## dzaima/APL, <s>80</s> <s>79</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```apl
' P  FL6BDEZQA SY574H TVOK J 08  M  U IC92XW 3G1RN'⊇⍨52|8965|2411⊥¨⎕ucs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5NSgNBEIX3OUXtOlkIzpiJyTIzavtXGttoWe4GJSAoCOJGsh4xEFHEIwg5h0fpi4yvO4lMN0O9nnrv45WP9xu3L@XdQ1lPfPXRrg2NiPaOe/nO7vXZkM412@7u0/jy9IgOabNPxEQXdFAM0iuhLZu4E@Nnr36@yNJpf9DLpmk3Sfzs53fh37@fb57qTgsC6AkZZmE2ZMThYjqc5rTMbE30CTfeyhpzax9erOaf66svP3/z1We7RYCz2JBXtayQObwCLYqNCwsrJhgtO@DxhYORo52LEhsXcuyWRoRgVFU4hG0eWSgJEog21FwTZUWUJTGAuFgRXcMohYQqWITfkA60HOmgxcaOnfoP)

Comment: what special features does your APL have?

Comment: @Jonah Here the only used thing is `⊇` (similar to `{⍵[⍺]}`), other than that, [these](https://github.com/dzaima/APL/blob/master/docs/chars.txt) two [files](https://github.com/dzaima/APL/blob/master/docs/differences.txt) contain info about it

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```
40ö98%•Wþ@»Ý¢a:µ@,–çòßuÒ¹₃©6µć‚FVÝ∊J?•2ôžLR‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xSwNBEIX/ihzYXRGCiElj2AMHxGm2yHCIRQIprCzE/tBCsdQuEELSBFsxggRS7CR/ZP/IOezsHFvsx5uZ997D42R6P2vbsx7/Di5OY7Mm3o/CjhdhPRmG7aiMzSdv@JuXT/wR/uLzS/g6D9vDa2zmV2NexLf360s56/PPcX/jY7Nq29uCEJGK8qSoASABOfIGLoFsOJcUnxUBvSJ0eYSdYjuiYHJGeXrl1bmW0KxYloBXyH3QzsmKSZL1qXXkzRCpy0IFkB9yujqLQpX1STuVB1dbBKhzl46VyzUIFQANdJkcSPrdPw)

Takes input as array of columns, and outputs an array of characters.

Explanation:

```
40ö                       # convert each column from base 40
   98%                    # modulo 98
      •...•2ô             # compressed array: [20, 32, 82, 30, 27, 28, 76, 89, 46, 96, 36, 4, 18, 12, 80, 75, 50, 86, 42, 2, 52, 92, 48, 0, 84, 1, 88, 90, 10, 26, 70, 41, 94, 64, 14, 60]
             žLR          # built-in array 0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
                ‡         # transliterate
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>143</s> 128 bytes

```r
function(v)c(0:9,LETTERS)[match(colSums((sapply(v,U<-utf8ToInt)*194:198)%%45:41),U("#</Eb=,n9J.M4Z+%*V N[Hd\\B?1Oj>KgRYT2")+34)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVLRTttAEHz3V0RGkc/gtE1JJRKlVLXjXoAsbjcJ24P0IXWVlgocVBwkvj6dOzuBlNeeZd2eZ2Zn99Z/1ot@a71YFXl5vSzUQ5irN71uNEonk5TH4dXtvMx/qXx5M17d3it1P7@7u3lUD9G031qVi6PJ8qQow/12t9Nrd4/CZrPzrtdph9FU@Xv91@n391HRPX1FncuD5v5F4/xq@GM2iz@0s9/HZz/ZTN764cFhJ/y23muQMGvSho2HAzMTFhMOAoSEDFOjddwYpqNRJhmPBhue1DwSEWQgMZ63ULkKyEJBFAjjwQ7yzq7hoLGDJ/TsbMg43YaHE5kgDD0vn5cqaP3fNSsCZEabhOpRiDGaDMIYpmJsO0DYAloS8DS6Je2uxzYOntgNLxC2MmyWBwl4xhgQhHTsMqFX5EE@7bq1NzoZpl@mJ8lZzJmcf8q@nk7pczrILlIGMvp4aQaZHlfGUhtLZWz9KKmN2SaMHU8SsfXiu/2KkGEaC7lYNArAiNyMfNShtR81fDcsG7hp2QBqSSoIkYPArQI7GQQeMFPJ7NDMJqBaT5vUUnPoyYOd/hlJV1iMJTu2Vr7xcLJtjZ5Laf5xoyTeaWRb0YtmvScS1y35sr2IWHNdSC17YWb1rkg/YR0b3/6j678)

Function taking a vector of strings (corresponding to the columns) as input e.g. :

```r
MWRRG
MRRRM
WWRRM -> c('MMWMM','WRWRW','RRRRW','RRRRW','GMMMG') -> HELLO
MRRRM
MWWWG
```

Explanation :

Performing the following operation for each encoded string (e.g 'CRGBY' = 'S') :

```r
        TO ASCII      MULTIPLICATION             MODULO              SUM &              TO
        CODEPOINT                                                    OFFSET             ASCII
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'C'        67        67 * 194 = 12998       12998 %% 45 = 38  \
'R'        82        82 * 195 = 15990       15990 %% 44 = 18  |
'G'  --->  71  --->  71 * 196 = 13916  ---> 13916 %% 43 = 27  |---> (140 - 34) = 106 ---> 'j'
'B'        66        66 * 197 = 13002       13002 %% 42 = 24  |
'Y'        89        89 * 198 = 17622       17622 %% 41 = 33  /
```

we obtain the following string `'#</Eb=,n9J.M4Z+%*V N[Hd\B?1Oj>KgRYT2'` where each character corresponds to `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'`.

So, the code performs the described operations on the input strings, then searches their correspondences inside `'#</Eb=,n9J.M4Z+%*V N[Hd\B?1Oj>KgRYT2'` obtaining the positions in string `'0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR'`.

Comment: This looks clever but it’s not clear how to use the code: What shall I pass to the function? Both a list of character vectors and a plain vector fail with “non-conformable argument”. So does a character matrix.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: added a minimal explanation of the input (and changed the TIO in order to be more explicit). As soon as I can I'll add an explanation of the code, which I'm sure can be improved by finding an other "hashing" function for the strings returning values in the ASCII range instead of unicode...

Comment: @digEmAll yeah I've been playing with modding down the digits to a more reasonable range of distinct characters but nothing yet

Comment: @digEmAll Ah that works (I had the data as col-major rather than row-major) but your example results in “HEKKN”, not “HELLO”. I’m very confused that it appears to work on TIO. Different (non-UTF-8) encoding, I guess.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: yeah, probably. Consider that there's also a not-printable character among them (ASCII=1) so maybe copying-pasting from TIO doesn't work well...

Comment: @KonradRudolph: added a brief explanation (and found a shorter code) ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
ＷＳ§”*&_⟲⎇4>υ≧Y⪪ml^π≕t.A；p↶⧴q⊗Ｈε‖r¡¡ºÞd⸿σＣ⁺⮌”﹪﹪﹪⍘ιWMYCBGR³⁶⁰¦¹¹³¦⁷¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3JqsJAEEX3@YpLVt0QwRifA66MQ17UcohD2@6CBg2E5BHj8Pf9CtSFVXDugVtQx0tcHos4M@ZxSbMEIsz/btW6KtP8LKTEkqUS/SrMT8lT2IsdRvvO73ow/gn7mGETAG4bhGU38tEEpjjoBuoTBaDlrTAfsmxhO6DidMsK8R1@fE3ez1IHtiI98IPIlg68Vp3puh6z7Uope8YQKSJLRbxWxPNhQESBxa2it2vSfPlq2UhbpnbP/gE) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of columns terminated with a blank line. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Input strings until one is blank.

```
§”*&_⟲⎇4>υ≧Y⪪ml^π≕t.A；p↶⧴q⊗Ｈε‖r¡¡ºÞd⸿σＣ⁺⮌”
```

Cyclically index into the string `OV EX8HSCF5IA L TG  17 M P9RB 4  K ZY2 0JW   63Q ND   U` which (with trailing space) is 56 characters long.

```
﹪﹪﹪⍘ιWMYCBGR³⁶⁰¦¹¹³¦⁷¹
```

Perform base-7 conversion using the alphabet `WMYCBGR` and then reduce successively modulo 360, 113, 71, and 56 implicitly via the cyclic indexing.

My base 7 approach fared really badly with @Arnauld's fixed font; after some searching I was still at 73 bytes. Using @Grimy's approach cut this down to 67 bytes. However I eventually tracked down a 66 byte solution:

```
ＷＳ§”*&″ÀＭ↔↓<Ｊ;×⊟ςF,Ｇηe↖ητγ´ＷＩＹ³﹪▶⟧9?δc⁶ＡxDê↷hＰiψ”﹪﹪﹪⍘ι⁴⁷¦²³⁷¦⁷³¦⁶⁷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1LC4JQEIX3/oqDq3vBoNKyaNXTrKZMK7OdpJQgGmaPf3@79lh0Br754AzM8RwWxzxMhXickzQGs7PLrfTKIslOjHM4UkrWL@0sip9MtUeY9qlhdrDzjAl0F2OnPVwDB2wHWKEO7IEuqlhvtjbL2XzRDCr3VQ2UR7c0Z/9rEF7j789Eg2FyDU29oqlLtE3OeU8IIp9I8V05iivzo0VEliJbn74eUCAvP600ChRRu6cv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Input strings until one is blank.

```
§”*&″ÀＭ↔↓<Ｊ;×⊟ςF,Ｇηe↖ητγ´ＷＩＹ³﹪▶⟧9?δc⁶ＡxDê↷hＰiψ”
```

Cyclically index into the string `ID HAM178 VS4F 3R EP6CQ  Z UB O 0  X  9     G     5TNJKL2Y    W` which is 63 characters long.

```
﹪﹪﹪⍘ι⁴⁷¦²³⁷¦⁷³¦⁶⁷
```

Perform base-47 conversion using the alphabet `0-9A-Za-k` and then reduce successively modulo 237, 73, 67, and 63 implicitly via the cyclic indexing.

Answer (score 2):

#### CJam (63 bytes)

```
{{Gb"õáÖÅ{a("{i%}/"@/Ö´çýß}yùÜÅ©GôÉç¢"256b43b'0f+=}%}
```

or in xxd format

```
0000000: 7b7b 4762 22f5 e1d6 c59f 7b61 2822 7b69  {{Gb".....{a("{i
0000010: 257d 2f22 0b8a 8340 982f d6b4 e793 fddf  %}/"...@./......
0000020: 7d79 f9dc c519 17a9 0e47 0ef4 c9e7 a222  }y.......G....."
0000030: 3235 3662 3433 6227 3066 2b3d 7d25 7d    256b43b'0f+=}%}
```

This is an anonymous block (function) which expects input as a list of columns. [Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%25%0A%0A%20%20%7B%7BGb%22%C3%B5%C3%A1%C3%96%C3%85%C2%9F%7Ba(%22%7Bi%25%7D%2F%22%0B%C2%8A%C2%83%40%C2%98%2F%C3%96%C2%B4%C3%A7%C2%93%C3%BD%C3%9F%7Dy%C3%B9%C3%9C%C3%85%19%17%C2%A9%0EG%0E%C3%B4%C3%89%C3%A7%C2%A2%22256b43b'0f%2B%3D%7D%25%7D%0A%0A~&input=WMMMW%0AYGGGW%0AWBWRW%0ABWWBW%0AMMWBB%0ARRWBW%0ARRWMW%0AMMBBB%0AMMWMW%0AMMWBW%0AWMWMM%0AYMYMY%0AWRRRW%0AYMMMY%0AWRWRW%0AWRWRR%0AWRMMW%0AMMWMM%0AWGGGW%0ABBBBW%0AMMYMM%0ARRRRW%0AMWWMM%0AYMMMM%0AGMMMG%0AYMYRR%0AGMMWC%0AYMYMM%0ACRGBY%0AWGGGG%0AMMMMW%0AMMMCB%0AMMWWM%0AMMGMM%0AMMGGG%0AWBGRW).

As many of the other answers, this does a base conversion followed by a chain of % to get a short lookup table. In this case I use base 16 and % chain `[245 225 214 197 159 123 97 40]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 48 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki.Code-page)

```
OḌ%⁽qƥ%⁹%53“ð×⁼ẎėWWæ¤jḌṛ>÷ƭÑṙsṛḌz0Ġọµḷ’b51¤iⱮịØB
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of uppercase characters (each being a column) which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZC/TsMwEMZfpUuVpQMIdWVwBk8nJC8nq2KpxNCqC2KCqZ0pSExtBUOHwlYEA2pDYYmrvof9IuZs51DCgD3k893vuz8ZXoxG196f2e207Sbfl4dn@hTt7okbP5k3M3OTL/t5v58hmpdyNSTMFo@nZnNYmwdbLK7oRbGbo/3S7u7KD7vduPGi3z0uVwP3/mp3t2YuvPe9DAEAs04rQ0knCHoDxIiiG4SmTBSScnliaq4klEowgK7sgu0U0SygqgPcCyGlIKUEko@7qz@wTAy5hIgwHWzME@pVBXWy50qK2J3mI7jVqReEXDQ35QkJhgj/81sAqH1gFO@Ov4yQzNTsyJvqxl6oeHgIE57/AA)**

#### How?

```
OḌ%⁽qƥ%⁹%53“...’b51¤iⱮịØB - Link: columns
O                         - ordinals
 Ḍ                        - convert from base ten
  %⁽qƥ                    - modulo 29415
      %⁹                  - modulo 256
        %53               - modulo 53
                    iⱮ    - map with first index of x in:
                   ¤      -   nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
           “...’          -     22270425059867513817410846141176204460122938458128124185752719
                b         -     convert to base
                 51       -       51
                          -     ... = [38,13,19,27,10,16,20,11,35,31,4,17,9,0,50,45,24,25,34,39,22,29,41,32,3,7,46,5,48,18,6,44,28,14,1,8]
                      ị   - index into
                       ØB -   "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 109 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.map{|i|"6&\278$Cc\17Y9\23T\r]{v^Ox\16_+!Qj\fbH
hraD*Ap".index((i.to_i(36)%245%119+8).chr).to_s(36)}*""}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk8vN7GguiazRslMLcbI3ELFOTnG0DzSMsbIOCSmKLa6LM6/IsbQLF5bMTArJi3JgyujKNFFy7FASS8zLyW1QkMjU68kPz5Tw9hMU9XIxFTV0NBS20JTLzmjSBMkUQySqNVSUqr9X6CQFh2t7usb7uurrqMeHgSEQDoICJBpd19fX3f12Nj/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 46 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
é►^njÖ_╪»Θîq╪↨δXû=▀úæ5?ªoéV╫╫╩ßH‼╒C═e┼$⌠°JqUu⌡
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=82105e6e6a995fd8afe98c71d817eb58963ddfa391353fa66f8256d7d7cae14813d543cd65c524f4f84a715575f5&i=WYWBMRRMMMWYWYWWWMWBMRMYGYGYCWMMMMMW%0AMGBWMRRMMMMMRMRRRMGBMRWMMMMMRGMMMMMB%0AMGWWWWWBWWWYRMWWMWGBYRWMMYMYGGMMWGGG%0AMGRBBBMBMBMMRMRRMMGBMRMMMRWMBGMCWMGR%0AWWWWBWWBWWMYWYWRWMWWMWMMGRCMYGWBMMGW%0A%0AWMWGMWWMYYGMYWGMBMMYWYGMWYWMWRWWMYGW%0AGMRMMGRMMMMMMRMMBMWMRMMMRMGMRRMBMMMR%0AGWWMMGRYYYMWMWMGBMWYWMMMWYGWWRWGGMMM%0AGMRWMGRMMMMWMRMMBMMRRMMCRMGMRRMRGMMM%0AGMWCWWWMYMGMMRGMWWMRWYGBWMGMWWMWGYGW&a=1&m=1)

Each column is decoded as base-36.  Successive modulus of 8273, then 95 are applied.  This yields a unique number, looked up in a fixed string.

It takes input exactly in the format specified in the examples, and has to transpose them to get columns.  I will be able to save some bytes by using some different input format, which I may do at some point.